# Using Ruby and SCP/SSH, how to determine if a file exists before uploading a copy

Tags: ruby, file-upload, scp, net-ssh

I'm uploading a file to a remote server using SCP, but what's the proper way of seeing if that file exists before doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware check-then-upload: this is not atomic and may lead to race conditions (or TOCTOU vulnerabilities).

A better way forwards might be to set the file permissions on the uploaded file so that it is not writable (400 or 444 or similar on UNIX-like systems), then any subsequent uploads to the same filename will simply fail. (You'll get "permission denied" back which may be subject to a little interpretation (eg did the upload directory permissions change?). This is one downside to this method).

How do you set permissions on the remote file? The simplest way to do that is to set them on the local file and then preserve them when you do the upload. Ruby's Net::SCP [README](http://net-ssh.github.com/scp/v1/api/files/README_rdoc.html) says that it can indeed "preserve file attributes across transfers".

Answer (score 11):

You can't do this with scp. However you can do it with [sftp.](http://net-ssh.rubyforge.org/sftp/v2/api/index.html) 
It would look something like this:

```
require 'net/sftp'

remote_path = "/path/to/remote/file"
Net::SFTP.start('host', 'username', :password => 'password') do |sftp|
  sftp.stat!(remote_path) do |response|
    unless response.ok?
    sftp.upload!("/path/to/local/file", remote_path)
  end
end
```

Comment: The line `sftp.stat!(...)` will raise an exception if the `remote_path` does not exist. It should say `sftp.stat(...)`

Answer (score -2):

This definitely solves your question and will give extra information as well. http://ruby.about.com/od/ssh/ss/netscp.htm